# Update selected entries using CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a GridView in my ASP.NET-WebApplication.
Simply said, the GridView contains two columns, one with the GUID and another with a checkbox.
On top of the GridView there is a button called "`Update selected entries`", which, well, updates the checked entries.
I collect the checked entries in a string like this:

```
Dim sAllTheIDs As String = ""
For Each dRow As GridViewRow In myGridView.Rows
    If dRow.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If DirectCast(dRow.FindControl("myCheckBox"), CheckBox).Checked Then
            sAllTheIDs &= myGridView.DataKeys(dRow.RowIndex).Value.ToString() & ", "
        End If
    End If
Next

'remove the ", " to make it a valid parameter
If sAllTheIDs.Length > 0 Then
    sAllTheIDs = sAllTheIDs.Remove(sAllTheIDs.Length - 2, 2)
End If
```

The upadte itself is done with a stored procedure, which looks like this:

```
declare @sSQL   nvarchar(max)
set @sSQL = 'UPDATE dbo.myTable ' +
            'SET myColumn = myValue ' +
            'WHERE CHARINDEX(CAST(myGUID as nvarchar(50)),@sAllTheIDs) > 0 '

exec sp_executesql @sSQL, N'@sAllTheIDs as nvarchar(4000)', @sAllTheIDs
```

This seems to work just fine, but if there 30+ GUIDs it exceeds the default timeout of 30 seconds (updating 50 entries takes about a minute).
Things I already did to increase performance:

- created indexes where needed
- set SET NOCOUNT ON;/SET NOCOUNT OFF;
- using `dbo.` with my tables and also when calling the SP in VB.NET (`.CommandText = "dbo.sp_UpdateEntries"`)

I looked at the execution plan of it and it seems that the step `Clustered Index Update` takes about 60% operation costs.
How can I improve the performance of this operation? Is using `CHARINDEX` the right way here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are constructing the query from strings, then `charindex()` is not the most efficient operation.  Instead, construct a series of comparisons.  I don't know what the format of `@sAllTheIds` is, but something like this might work:

```
'WHERE 1=0'+replace(@sAllTheIds, ',', ' OR myGuid = ')
```

For other data types, I would suggest just using `in` but GUIDs are more difficult.  Also, you may need to have string delimiters or cast operations for the GUIDs in the comparison list.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great idea, will try that out!